# Backup table with all information and structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 million records. I want copy some of them (beginning from **CreationDate**) with all their dependencies into an archive table that has the same structure and then delete the copied rows from the main table. I know how to copy all data via "Generate scripts" and then insert into archive table, but how to copy only some rows? What I have already done: used "Generate script" to build archive table similar to main.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArchiveTable]
([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,  – ForeignKey
[CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[StatusId] [int] NOT NULL,  – ForeignKey
[ProductId] [int] NULL, – ForeignKey}
```

Comment: do you store the archive on the same database or at least the same server ?

Comment: Gabriel Durac yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on the same DB you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ArchiveTable] (Id,UserId,CreationDate,StatusId,ProductId)
SELECT Id,UserId,CreationDate,StatusId,ProductId
FROM YourTable
WHERE condition
```